# Compiled javascript file have the duplicate variable declaration in the class constructor while using access modifiers in typescript class

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to build a class in typescript which have few of the properties with access modifiers as in the below code.

```
class Coder {
    age : number;

    constructor(
    public readonly name : string,
    age : number,
    public lang : string,
    private address : string,
    protected id : number = 234
    )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.address = address;
        this.id = Math.random();
    }

    getName()
    {
        return `My name is ${this.name}`;
    }
}

let coder = new Coder('Nayan', 28, 'JavaScript', 'LMP');

// Not possible as name is readOnly
// coder.name = 'Golu';
```

But the compiled code has the class with duplicate property decalation in the constructor as in the below code.

Once I try to remove any of the modifiers then the duplicate property get removed in compiled js file too (see age property).

```
"use strict";
class Coder {
    constructor(name, age, lang, address, id = 234) {
        this.name = name;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.address = address;
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.address = address;
        this.id = Math.random();
    }
    getName() {
        return `My name is ${this.name}`;
    }
}
let coder = new Coder('Nayan', 28, 'JavaScript', 'LMP');
// Not possible as name is readOnly
// coder.name = 'Golu';
```

Not sure why is this happening as it is just violating the DRY rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because any access modifier on variables passed in the constructor compiles to exactly that - a declaration on the class and an assignment inside the constructor.

```js
class Test {
   constructor(public whatever: string){}
}
```

is the same as

```js
class Test {
   public whatever: string;
   constructor(whatever: string) {
      this.whatever = whatever;
   }
}
```

so if you write

```js
class Test {
   constructor(public whatever: string){
      this.whatever = whatever;
   }
}
```

it would be equivalent to

```js
class Test {
   public whatever: string;
   constructor(whatever: string) {
      this.whatever = whatever; 
      this.whatever = whatever;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using modifiers you don't need to explicitly map the variable yourself, it's your own code that is the reason for the duplicate. Remove this when using access modifiers:

```
this.name = name;
```